# Execute program file with irb and remain interactive

Tags: ruby, irb

Is it possible to run irb, pass it a .rb file that gets automatically executed, and have irb stay running in interactive mode?

On Windows, I have a file called **checkme.bat** that basically does the following:

```
irb checkme.rb
```

The problem right now is that when I run checkme.bat, irb executes the program file but then simply exits, leaving me back at the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `pry` and add the line `binding.pry` at the point in your script where you want to bail out into the repl.

```
x = 3
puts "Hello!"
binding.pry
```

Then you can run your script with pry and it'll let you examine what's going on.

```
~> pry d.rb
Hello
[1] pry(main)> x
=> 3
[2] pry(main)>
```

Comment: This seems to be the ticket for me, Bill. By adding `binding.pry` to the end of my checkme.rb file and calling pry from my BAT file, I'm able to stay on an interactive prompt after building the gem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure but on Windows when you execute a .rb file it instantly closes, try using `gets` at the end of the program.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately `gets` just prompts me to enter something and then exits as soon as I press Enter.